# non global scope and nested functions

Tags: php

I need to make a PHP program with the following structure:

```
function start(){

    $n = 0;

    $then = function() use ($n){
        ++$n;
        echo '$n was increased by 1<br />';
    };

    $then();
    echo '$n = '.$n;

}

start();
```

If you run it you will get:

```
$n was increased by 1
$n = 0
```

I would like to get $n = 1 as it should be...

```
$n was increased by 1
$n = 1
```

The requirements are very strict: $n must be declared inside the start() function, the $then function must be anonymus and $n cannot be passed as a parameter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use $n as a reference in the $then function (&$n), it will work:

```
function start(){

  $n = 0;

  $then = function() use (&$n){
    ++$n;
    echo '$n was increased by 1<br />';
  };

  $then();
  echo '$n = '.$n;

}

start();
```

More information about references can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php